How can I see the console output in Compiler Explorer (Godbolt)?
If I compile a piece of code that writes to the console I can't see anything, only the assembly code on the right. Link. How I can I see what's printed from a call to std::cout?

Click Output then Execute the code. You can also use  Add new/Execution only instead of Add new/Compiler if you're not interested in the assembly.

The compiler pane has a "(GEAR) Output..." menu, with a "[_] Execute the code" checkbox.

@TedLyngmo You can't click the output button, it has a red cross icon on it if you hover it, you can see in the link I gave.

@Zebrafish It has no red cross icon for me. I just clicked it and added Execute the code: https://godbolt.org/z/6croEdTax. Does Add new/Execution only work?

@Zebrafish it's the "output..." at the top, with the cogwheel. Not the "output (0/0)" at the bottom
